# Create buttons where clicked anywhere do navigation

Tags: html, css

This is probably a very simple question for many of you, but I can't seem to figure it out and I've been at it for about an hour now.

I'm trying to create a navigation bar with buttons.  I'd like the buttons to have the following features, but I can't figure out how to implement them:

- Clicking anywhere on the button will activate the button redirection.
- The font is not underlined or recolored like a regular text hyperlink.
- The font is much more "fat" (I don't know how else to describe it.

In the picture, I put small red cross to signal that I'd like to be able to click in those locations for it to work.

I've included a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxre4x2k/1/) with what I've been able to accomplish thusfar.

**My html:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="nav" href="#">Page1</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav" href="#">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav" href="#">Page3</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav" href="#">Page4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**My CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0px
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {

    float:left;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
    background-color: grey;

    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: yellow;
}

ul li:hover{
    background-color: black;   
}
}
```

[image: Examples I'd like to copy.]

Comment: something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vxre4x2k/5/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `ul li {` with `ul li a{` and `ul li:hover{` with `ul li a:hover{`

http://jsfiddle.net/vxre4x2k/2/

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace `ul li` with `ul li a` and `ul li:hover` with `ul li a:hover`.

To make the font thicker or thinner change your `font-weight`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make you anchors work like block elements. The LI's will contain the anchor.

```
ul li a {
    display: block;

    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: inline-block` to `a(anchor element)` and give it some `padding` for your first request(Clicking anywhere on the button will activate the button redirection.). Also you can remove underline with `text-decoration: none;` and reduce "fat" from font with `font-weight: 100;`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: yellow;
}
ul li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
ul li {
  padding: 0;
}
ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="nav" href="#">Page1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="nav" href="#">Page2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="nav" href="#">Page3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="nav" href="#">Page4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**References:**

[font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight)

[text-decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Answer (score 0):

Clicking anywhere on the button will activate the button redirection.

to do this, wrap your list elements with the anchor elements instead.
ex.

```
<a href='#'><li>foo</li></a>
```

The font is not underlined or recolored like a regular text hyperlink.

for the links you gave them each an id of "nav". This isn't recommended as its commonplace to set id's to individual elements. I would look up the difference between CSS id's and classes. In short, classes are used for multiple elements that share the same styles. In this case you would use a class so it should be:

```
<a class="nav" href="#"><li>Page1</li></a>
```

The styles for the class to remove the underline would be:

```
.nav{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: black;
}
```

The font is much more "fat" (I don't know how else to describe it.
are you saying you want it to be fat?
if so then try this:

```
<a class="nav" href="#"><strong><li>Page1</li></strong></a>
```

or you could also set the css style font-weight property

the font-weight property can be used to increase or decrease the "fattness" of the font.
if that doesn't do it for you i'd suggest using a different font.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  I'll have to research the classes and ids.